Mocking a property on an object using an interface - cannot pass to method to be tested
I have a method Apply() that I'd like to write a unit test for:
public override MyList Apply(MyProduct product, MyState state) 
{
    if (product.Name == "Special Name") 
    {
        state.MyProperty = 0;
        return null;
    } 
    else
    {
        return base.Apply(product, context, state);
    }
}

MyProduct inherits from another class, which inherits from BaseProduct, which contains the Name property:
public class BaseProduct 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

I thought I could create a mock that returns "Special Name" for the Name property to test this method, but I kept getting an exception stating that the getter is non-overrideable and cannot be used in setup/verification - I set it up like so:
var mock = new Mock<MyProduct>();
mock.SetupProperty(product => product.Name);
mock.SetupGet(product => product.Name).Returns("Special Name");

I'm having trouble mocking properties on MyProduct in a way that allows me to pass an object to Apply() that matches the method signature.
As an attempted solution, I created an interface for my test:
public class IBaseProduct {
    string Name { get; set; }
}

In my test, I set the mock up like so:
var mock = new Mock<MyProduct>().As<IBaseProduct>();
mock.SetupProperty(product => product.Name);
mock.SetupGet(product => product.Name).Returns("Special Name");

I'm able to verify that mock.Object.Name returns "Special Name," but when I try to pass mock.Object to Apply(), I see that the class of the object is IBaseProduct rather than MyProduct.
Is this because MyProduct (or BaseProduct) is not declared to implement IBaseProduct? I'd like to be able to write this test without changing MyProduct or BaseProduct.
I tried casting mock.Object to MyProduct like so:
Apply((MyProduct)mock.Object, state)

But when I do so, mock.Object.Name then returns null instead of "Special Name."
How can I set this test up to mock MyProduct and return the correct Name without changing MyProduct or BaseProduct to implement IBaseProduct?

What if you just make BaseProduct.Name virtual and forget about the interface?

You can only 'mock' interfaces and virtual members: stackoverflow.com/a/1973482/126014

In C# you can mock interface members (as you did with IProduct) or abstract members.
I don't quite understand why do you want to mock it in first place.
Mocking make sense where you have service/dependency of some sort, which is not available during test or is not practical to create it (so databases, services with some logic in it). You have simple POCO (plain old C# object), which does not have to be mocked.
Just set it explicitly:
var product = new Product() { Name = "Special Name" };
Apply(product, state);


The  Product class is actually quite large and laborious to instantiate. Our existing unit tests aren't actually unit tests, but rather integration tests.

@AvaStark What do you mean by "laborious to instantiate"? If you mean you have to write lot of code that creates stuff, maybe you should take a look at AutoFixture nuget and its magnificient Fixture class. With it you would need just to do new Fixture.Create<Product>(); - this single line of code would create object with prefilled all properties. Then you can set Name to desired value you want to test against.
